# Catching Throwable Errors

Tags: java, exception

Need your feedback on the below code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Inside catch");
    } catch (Throwable t){
        System.out.println("Inside catch throwable");
    }finally {
        System.out.println("Inside finally");
    }
}
```

Here I am throwing an OutOfMemoryError object (using new operator) from try clause & catching Throwable object. So I get the output "Inside catch throwable" & "Inside finally". But since we are throwing OutofMemError shouldn't the code exit (i.e. without going to Throwable & finally)? In actual practical project, if we get OutOfMemoryError, the application just exits... why this difference?

Comment: this is why you don't catch `Throwable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Errors can be caught too (unless they crash the VM or something), and Java 6 onwards allows catching OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

`OutOfMemoryError` is a sub-class of `Error` class which is a sub-class of `Throwable` class. and this is why it prints out:

> Inside catch throwable

Answer (score 4):

No, the code won't exit, because you are swallowing the exception. The 'traditional Java program' you described crashes on this kind of error because the exception is not handled. You can test this yourself by installing a default exception handler on the main thread of your program.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

   @Override
   public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
   }
});

throw new OutOfMemoryError();
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what exception or error or sub-class of Throwable (which doesn't have to be an exception or an error) you can catch the Throwable.

Nothing can cause the thread to exit exception `System.exit(0);` try that instead.